# Вставка значения в БД access через код VBA

Tags: access, vba, office, visual-basic

Столкнулся с проблемой, что в запрос с параметрами нельзя передавать значение>255 символов(MEMO) из-за чего вылетает ошибка "invalid property value".

Если вставку осуществлять запросом через `currentDb.Execute("INSERT INTO ... VALUES")`, то все хорошо, но метод может споткнуться на строке, где в тексте будут кавычки=> нужно все экранировать.

Подскажите, можно ли это как-нибудь обойти(проблема с запросов с параметром)?

Если нет, то нет ли стандартных методов экранирования или нужно ручками жкранировать кавычки перед вызовом `execute`?

Comment: А почему не хотите вставлять записи через ADODB.Recordset? там этих заморочек не будет... при желании можно всё это упаковать в функцию-обёртку, которую один раз отладить - и на всю жизнь забыть о проблемах.

Comment: @Akina, там, вроде, тоже ограничение но в 512.

Comment: ADODB.Recordset.Field.AppendChunk - и хоть слона засовывай...

Comment: @Akina, а без RecordSet никак нельзя? Через запрос с параметрами?